# error in post method of retrofit library

Tags: java, android, web-services, retrofit

I am using retrofit library for web services.when i am using get method for the service it gives me proper result but when i am using post method to call web service i am not getting desire result i always get one result only i.e 0

This service is login service and for i am using post request so please read my code i.e. given below and give me solutions

my code is here

interface in retrofit

```
@POST("/api.php?rquest=login")
public void authUser(@Body String un,
        Callback<String> cb);
```

here is  main activity code

```
EditText etun, etpass;
Button btnlogin;
String endpoint = "http://androidums.developtechtutorial.com/rest";
ProgressDialog pd;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // find components

    etun = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etun);
    etpass = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etpass);

    btnlogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnlogin);

    btnlogin.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            String un = etun.getText().toString().trim();
            String pass = etpass.getText().toString();

            pd = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
            pd.setCancelable(false);
            pd.setMessage("Loading Please Wait...........");
            pd.show();

            RestAdapter adapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()
                    .setLogLevel(LogLevel.FULL).setEndpoint(endpoint)
                    .setLogLevel(LogLevel.FULL).build();

            LoginApi obj = adapter.create(LoginApi.class);
            System.out.println("Username " + un + " Passowrd " + pass);

            JSONObject objjson = new JSONObject();
            try {
                objjson.put("pwd", pass);
                objjson.put("un", un);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO: handle exception
            }

            String data = objjson.toString();
            System.out.println("json object ...................." + data);

            obj.authUser(data, new Callback<String>() {

                @Override
                public void success(String arg0, Response arg1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    pd.dismiss();
                    System.out.println("ARg0...................... "
                            + Integer.parseInt(arg0));

                }

                @Override
                public void failure(RetrofitError arg0) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    System.out
                            .println("Error .............................. "
                                    + arg0);

                }
            });

        }
    });
```

Comment: `rquest` are you sure of this parameter? that looks like a typo to me

Comment: show your complete logs, since you log what retrofit does

Comment: also, are you sure you are correctly using the api? have you the documentation somewhere?

Comment: yes i am using correct api i have right  result in case of get method but i didn't get the result in case of post method

Comment: here is my log output


08-03 05:07:17.523: D/Retrofit(2785): ---> HTTP POST http://androidums.developtechtutorial.com/rest/api.php?rquest=login
08-03 05:07:17.523: D/Retrofit(2785): Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
08-03 05:07:17.527: W/EGL_genymotion(2785): eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
08-03 05:07:17.539: D/Retrofit(2785): Content-Length: 36
08-03 05:07:17.559: D/Retrofit(2785): "{\"un\":\"aman\",\"pwd\":\"aman\"}"
08-03 05:07:17.587: D/Retrofit(2785): ---> END HTTP (36-byte body)

Comment: <--- HTTP 200 http://androidums.developtechtutorial.com/rest/api.php?rquest=login (11166ms)
08-03 05:07:28.779: D/Retrofit(2785): : HTTP/1.1 200 OK
08-03 05:07:28.799: D/Retrofit(2785): Content-Length: 1
08-03 05:07:28.819: D/Retrofit(2785): Content-Type: application/json

08-03 05:07:28.871: D/Retrofit(2785): Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.0
08-03 05:07:28.871: D/Retrofit(2785): X-Android-Received-Millis: 1438578448760
 D/Retrofit(2785): X-Android-Sent-Millis: 1438578438131
 D/Retrofit(2785): X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
: D/Retrofit(2785): <--- END HTTP (1-byte body)
: I/System.out(2785): Result  0

Answer (score 0):

You try to use POJO instead of  JSONObject

```
public class LoginObject{
 String pwd;
 String un;    
}
```

and send POJO

```
@POST("/api.php?rquest=login") public void authUser(@Body LoginObject un, Callback cb);
```

Comment: i didn't get the result can u tell me some more ways